# Building ViewModels based on nested Model Entities in WPF and MVVM Pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, nested, viewmodel

I have a problem understanding how to build view models based on the following models

(I simplified the models to be clearer)

```
public class Hit
{
   public bool On { get; set;}
   public Track Track { get; set; }
}
public class Track
{
   public ObservableCollection<Hit> Hits { get; set; }
   public LinearGradientBrush Color { get; set; }
   public Pattern Pattern { get; set; }
}
public class Pattern
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ObservableCollection<Tracks> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

Now, my problem is, how to build the ViewModels..

I need to keep the original relationships through the models, beacaus i have a Serialize() method on the Pattern that serializes it to an XML file.. (with the related Tracks and Hits)

To be able to bind the pattern to the user controls and it's nested templates I should also have a PatternViewModel with an ObservableCollection<TrackViewModel> in it, same thing for the TrackViewModel and the HitViewModel.. and i neet to have custom presentation properties on the view models that aren't part of the business object (colors and more..)

It just seem not a good thing to me to duplicate all of the relationships of the models on the view models...
and keeping track of all this relations while coding the viewmodels is also much more error prone..

anyone has a better approach/solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using part of the solution that Joe White suggested, in a slighty differ manner

The solution was to just leave the models as they were at the beginning, and attaching to the collections an eventhandler for CollectionChanged of the inner collections, for example, the PatternViewModel would be:

```
public class PatternViewModel : ISerializable
{
    public Pattern Pattern { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TrackViewModel> Tracks { get; set; }

    public PatternViewModel(string name)
    {
        Pattern = new Pattern(name);
        Tracks = new ObservableCollection<TrackViewModel>();
        Pattern.Tracks.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Tracks_CollectionChanged);
    }

    void Tracks_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (Track track in e.NewItems)
                {
                    var position = Pattern.Tracks.IndexOf((Track) e.NewItems[0]);
                    Tracks.Insert(position,new TrackViewModel(track, this));
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (Track track in e.OldItems)
                    Tracks.Remove(Tracks.First(t => t.Track == track));
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                for (int k = 0; k < e.NewItems.Count; k++)
                {
                    var oldPosition = Tracks.IndexOf(Tracks.First(t => t.Track == e.OldItems[k]));
                    var newPosition = Pattern.Tracks.IndexOf((Track) e.NewItems[k]);
                    Tracks.Move(oldPosition, newPosition);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So i can attach the new Color/Style/Command on the view models to keep my base models clean

And whenever I add/remove/move items in the base models collection, the view models collections remain in sync with each other

Luckily I don't have to manage lots of object in my application, so duplicated data and performance won't be a problem

I don't like it too much, but it works well, and it's not a huge amount of work, just an event handler for the view model that contains others view model collections (in my case, one for PatternViewModel to sync TrackViewModels and another on TrackViewModel to manage HitViewModels)

Still interested in your thoughs or better ideas =)

Comment: +1 for sharing your solution. Nevertheless, I'm still amazed at how much binding code MVVM requires for even such "common" scenarios :-/

Answer (score 3):

One thing I've done, with some success, is to move the ObservableCollection out of the model. Here's my general pattern:

- In the model objects, expose a property of type `IEnumerable<TModel>` that gives read-only access to the collection. Use a plain old `List<TModel>`, not an ObservableCollection, as the backing collection.
- For code that needs to mutate the models' collections (add, delete, etc.), add methods to the model object. Don't have outside code directly manipulating the collection; encapsulate that inside methods on the model.
- Add events to the model for each type of change you allow. For example, if your model only supports adding items to the end of the collection, and deleting items, then you would need an ItemAdded event and an ItemDeleted event. Create an EventArgs descendant that gives information about the item that was added. Fire these events from the mutation methods.
- In your ViewModel, have an `ObservableCollection<TNestedViewModel>`.
- Have the ViewModel hook the events on the model. Whenever the model says an item was added, instantiate a ViewModel and add it to the ViewModel's ObservableCollection. Whenever the model says an item was deleted, iterate the ObservableCollection, find the corresponding ViewModel, and remove it.
- Apart from the event handlers, make sure all of the collection-mutation code is done via the model -- treat the ViewModel's ObservableCollection as strictly something for the view's consumption, not something you use in code.

This makes for a lot of duplicate code for each different ViewModel, but it's the best I've been able to come up with. It does at least scale based on the complexity you need -- if you have a collection that's add-only, you don't have to write much code; if you have a collection that supports arbitrary reordering, inserts, sorting, etc., it's much more work.

Comment: This is interesting, really, one of the cleaner approaches, but it is still an overkill in terms of code to write, i wish there was a good way, i tried thinking about subclassing the model, and loads of other solutions, but none is good enough.. and I can't find a good example of MVVM using Models with nested relationships either..

Comment: Yeah, it's a ridiculous amount of work, but it's the best way I've found. I wish one of the MVVM frameworks would apply conventions to automatically wrap a ViewModel around your Model, the same way they automatically discover Views for your ViewModels. Then you'd only need one ObservableCollection (in your model) and the rest would take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think I had the same problem and if you do it like "PatternViewModel with an ObservableCollection<TrackViewModel>" you also get a massive impact on your performance because you start duplicating data.

My approach was to build - for your expample - a PatternViewModel with a ObservableCollection<Track>. It's no contradiction to MVVM because the view is bound to the collection.

This way you may avoid the duplication of the relationships.

Comment: That's exactly the approach i'm using now, i'm binding a PatternViewModel that has an ObservableCollection of Tracks, but i'd like to add presentation logic on the Tracks and Hits, for example a Color Property on the HitViewModel that return the corrispondent Track Color, or a ToggleCommand, that turn it On and Off... and i'd need to add this presentation logic on the model not to duplicate the relationships and the data, but if i put presentation logic on the model, i end up not following the pattern..

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've been considering, although I'm not sure if it would work perfectly in practice, is to use converters to create a viewmodel around your model.

So in your case, you could bind `Tracks` directly to (as an example) a listbox, with a converter that creates a new `TrackViewModel` from the Track. All your control would ever see would be a `TrackViewModel` object, and all your models will ever see is other models.

I'm not sure about the dynamic updating of this idea though, I've not tried it out yet.